# Loading popups with $.get - Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to load some data from a server. I have some links that when I click on them, I want them to open the right corresponding popup with that data in them. But the popups just appears as formatted text on the page. If you look at the code they are containing `<p>` tags. The result of the `loadPopups` function is that it just prints the `<p>` tags to the page. No popup behaviour.

Here is my code to get the popup data

```
function loadPopups() {
    $.get("load.php", function(data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var str = '';

        for( laxa in data.laxor) {
        var laxaArray = data.laxor[laxa];
        str += '' +
               '<div data-role="popup" id="' + (laxaArray.laxa_id + 'rubrik') + '">' +
               '<p>' + laxaArray.rubrik + '<p>' +
               '</div>' +
               '<div data-role="popup" id="' + (laxaArray.laxa_id + 'beskrivning') + '">' +
               '<p>' + laxaArray.beskrivning + '<p>' +
               '</div>' +
               '';
        }
    //alert('Data loaded');
    $("#popup_containor").html(str).page();
    });
}
```

this then gets added to this `<div>`

```
<div id="popup_containor">
</div>
```

When I try to display the popup by using the same id that is specified in the for loop for each popup like this

```
<p><a href="#134rubrik" data-rel="popup">Hej</a><p>
```

Nothin happens. The popups are simply displayed as if there where no `<div data-role="popup">`

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `popup_containor` is a page div? if not, page div should be direct parent of popup div.

Comment: Oh didn't notice they were not, though this just causes the formatting to be wrong, they aren't popups just <p> tags on the page

Comment: Take a look at the updated question @Omar

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cp24T/ if this what you want, i'll add an answer. Should you need more details, pls let me know.

Comment: Use .load instead of $.get

Comment: Here is another demo with two options http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sb75M/

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you separate the logic?

1. Get whatever values you want first from server.
   let's say var a= 'string 1 from server', b='string 2' and so on.
2. Create functional popup in your page with no data.

   `<a href="#134rubrik" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Done</a>
       <div data-role="popup" id="134rubrik" data-overlay-theme="b">
           <p id="serverdata"> </p>
        </div>`
3. Than fill your popup using JS or jQuery:
   `document.getElementById('serverdata').value= a;`